# Using two `lookup stages` in an aggregate referring same table with different local fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Is it possible that I can use two `lookup stages` in a `single aggregate query` referring to the `same table` but with `different local fields`

Here is my code,

```
const aggregate = [
        {
          $match: {
            deleted: false,
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'user',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'users',
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'products',
            localField: 'product',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'products',
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'products',
            localField: 'otherProduct',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'otherProducts',
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            users: 1,
            products: 1,
            otherProducts: 1
          },
        },
      ];
```

These are the two lookups I used,

```
{
    $lookup: {
       from: 'products',
       localField: 'product',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'products',
    },
},
{
    $lookup: {
       from: 'products',
       localField: 'otherProduct',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'otherProducts',
    },
}
```

I am getting **empty response from the second `otherProducts` lookup**.

But, if first **`products lookup ($lookup: {from: 'products')`** is **removed** or **commented**, the `second` one is giving the data.

> But, if we add both lookups the second lookup is empty.

Comment: no, because I am using a version which doesnot support the functions used in the first answer given there, and I tried the second answer but of no luck.

Comment: Can you show your database schema?

Comment: your query is correct but i think you don't have data in db which satisfy both lookup

Comment: For MongoDB earlier than 3.6 it's not possible